# Bind specified property of the WebAPI controller's model

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I want to bind only specified property of the WebAPI controller's model and skip all another properties to the `DefaultModelBinder`.

For example I have json, which should be passed to the WebAPI controller:

```
{
   prop1: 1,
   prop2: "b",
   prop3: "c",
   currentTime: "Fri Feb 27 2015",
   references: 
   [
      { name: "Name 1", type: "Info"  },
      { name: "Name 2", type: "Warn" }
   ]
}
```

On the server-side there is a `HttpPost` action with the following signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveObject(ReferenceModel model)
{
   ...
}
```

Where `ReferenceModel` is:

```
public class ReferenceModel
{
   public int Prop1 {get; set;}
   public string Prop2 {get; set;}
   public string Prop3 {get; set;}
   public DateTime CurrentTime {get; set;}
   public List<BaseReferenceItem> References {get; set;}
}
```

I need for custom bind of `References` property, because I want to initialize this property at the runtime by objects of **derived types**.

For example if I will get `Prop1` with value `1` so I need to initialize this collection by objects of type `DerivedReferenceType1`:

```
Model.References = new List<BaseReferenceItem>()
   {
     new DerivedReferenceType1(){...},
     new DerivedReferenceType1(){...}
   }
```

If I will get `Prop1` with value `2` - of type `DerivedReferenceType2` and so on.

I've found potential solution in the `ModelBinder`, but I don't want to bind all properties at the model.

I know that it's can be easy implemented in the MVC model binders with the call of

```
base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
```

But how to do it in WebAPI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to write a custom `JsonConverter` to handle this situation:

```
public class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(ReferenceModel);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jsonObject = JObject.Load(reader);
        var result = new ReferenceModel();
        serializer.Populate(jsonObject.CreateReader(), result);

        result.References = new List<BaseReferenceItem>();
        foreach (var obj in jsonObject.GetValue("references", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (result.Prop1 == 1)
            {
                result.References.Add(obj.ToObject<DerivedReferenceType1>(serializer));
            }
            else if (result.Prop1 == 2)
            {
                result.References.Add(obj.ToObject<DerivedReferenceType2>(serializer));
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException(result.Prop1 + " is not supported value for Prop1");
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then you could decorate your main view model with this custom converter:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyConverter))]
public class ReferenceModel
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
    public DateTime CurrentTime { get; set; }
    public List<BaseReferenceItem> References { get; set; }
}
```

or if you prefer to do this without modifying your view models you could always register your custom converter during the bootstrap process:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API routes
    ...

    var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;

    jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new MyConverter());
}
```